# Minify CSS with Node-sass

Tags: css, node.js, minify, node-sass

I'm using SCSS in my NodeJS project and have my script working to turn all my seperate SCSS files into a single CSS file using the following command

```
node-sass -w public/css/scss/style.scss public/css/style.css
```

My only issue is that I also want the CSS file to be minified. Is this possible with Node-sass? The docs say there is an option for 'compact' but it doesn't seem to work when I try

```
node-sass -w compact public/css/scss/style.scss public/css/style.css
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In the [node-sass documentation](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) says you have to use 
`--output-style`, and it could be `nested | expanded | compact | compressed`. To minify use `compressed`

For example:

```
node-sass -w public/css/scss/style.scss public/css/style.css --output-style compressed
```

will minify the CSS.

Comment: node-sass is now deprecated. Even though this was correct back in 2016, it is recommended to use the Dart-SASS package as Roko C. Buljan answered with.

Comment: @dasper not sure if node-sass is also deprecated, maybe it uses soon Dart Sass?

Comment: @Timo in https://github.com/sass/node-sass explicitly put this warning on top:

Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

Answer (score 11):

node-sass supports outputting minified CSS with the `--output-style` parameter.

**outputStyle**

- Type: String
- Default: `nested`
- Values: `nested`, `expanded`, `compact`, `compressed`

After installing the node-sass npm package. I added the `build-css` line to my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss   public/css/main.css --output-style compressed",
  },
```

Then I simply need to type npm run build-css for the content inside my /scss/main.scss file to be transformed into compressed (minified) css inside the /public/css/main.min.css

More information can be found within the node-sass Github repo's documentation here https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outputstyle

Answer (score 8):

Since LibSass and Node Sass [are deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)
**use the [**Dart-SASS**](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass)  package: `npm install --save-dev sass`**

<sub>**`package.json`**</sub>

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "sass --style=compressed --watch src/scss:public/css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.32.7"
  }
}
```

To run it and watch changes to files, run in terminal:

```
npm run scss
```

given a folder structure like:

<sub>**`︎  package.json`**

**`︎  public`**

 **`︎  css`**

  **`︎  style.css`**  ← ***Minified and compressed***

**`︎  src`**

 **`︎  scss`**

   **`︎  style.scss`**</sub>

Answer (score -2):

`"scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o app/css"` This work for me

Comment: although this compiles, this will not unfortunately "minify". for that you will need to make use of the `--output-style compressed` flag