# How to run node-sass options within my Express.js application correctly

Tags: express, node-sass

I have the following setup in my custom Express application.

- I installed node-sass as dependency and is visible from my package.json file like so :

```json
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
  "twig": "^1.15.4"
}
```

- I am running `npm run watch` to get things going. It's working great:

```json
"scripts": {
  "watch-sass": "node-sass -w src/scss/ -o pub/css/",
  "watch-code": "nodemon --ext js,twig server.js",
  "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch-code watch-sass"
},
```

After reading some of the [Options](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options) we can use for node-sass from the official source, I thought I could simply place these options within my my server.js file like so, reload the server, and see the adjustments applied to my output file (i.e. pub/css/css_bundle.css).

```js
   const result = sass.renderSync({
     outputStyle: 'compressed', //compressed | nested | expanded | compact
     sourceMap: true, // or an absolute or relative (to outFile) path
   });
```

...But no matter what happens, (i.e. running my "npm run watch" command), my output file does not compress.

I'm new to this process of managing sass configuration options.  What am I missing or not doing correctly in order to manage and connect my node-sass options to my setup (i.e. everything inside of pub/css/)?

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a realization that I have good flexibility with setting options in both my package.json file (while developing the client side) and also in my server.js file (when the server restarts).  In my case, I can use the same options in both areas.  The following resources led me to this way of thinking for now.

- https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outfile
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#command-line-interface
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40592964/957186

In regards to getting my options working from the server side, the following adjustment to my code has helped me out!

```js
const mscss = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/', 'css_bundle.scss');
const mcss = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pub/css/', 'css_bundle.css');

sass.renderSync({
    file: mscss,
    outputStyle: 'compact', //compressed | nested | expanded | compact
    outFile: mcss,
    sourceMap: true, // or an absolute or relative (to outFile) path
}, function (err, result) {
    /*...*/
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('scss render completed');

    fs.writeFile(mcss, result.css, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            //file written on disk
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there.